# Is 2 closed questions and 2 (-1) downvoted questions enough for Stack Overflow to no accept questions?

Tags: support, bug, questions, closed-questions, down-votes

I only have 2 (-1) downvoted questions and 2 closed questions.  Is this enough for Stack Overflow to not accept questions anymore? Because I tried to post a question and it wouldn't let me.

Also, do downvotes on deleted questions still count towards this? Or is it over written into just a deleted question where the downvotes no longer matter?

Comment: Deleted questions do count.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I mean't as in the deleted question's down-votes that they have on them.

Comment: Deleted questions absolutely factor into the question ban, weather they have downvotes or not.  You almost certainly have deleted questions, so you need to improve them and get them undeleted.

Comment: @psubsee2003 What if they are silly questions that can't be improved and have too many downvotes and they are closed by users?

Comment: You have two deleted questions with scores of -7 and -1, respectively.

Comment: @Xero you don't have a lot of options as deleted questions are only soft deleted and never truly disappear.  If you are serious about getting unbanned, you might try to improve what you can and you never know what will happen.  Given the info from the Grinch (aka Robert Harvey) you really have only 1 extremely bad question, but improving the rest should help enough

Comment: If those deleted questions were actually unsalvageable, then let that be a lesson for next time. It's *possible* to get out of a question ban, as long as you improve and learn how to make good contributions to the site.

Comment: Building off of what @Dennis said, after improving, if people start to upvote them, you will get your question asking privilege back. If after a while, nothing happens, then come ask here again.